# .NET silverlight development tools

Tags: tools, web-tools, silverlight

What tools are necessary when developing efficiently with Silverlight 4? VS 2010 is a gimme, but what version? Is Pro enough? Premium? What about Expression Blend/Web/Both?

When considering VS 2010, premium comes with an MSDN subscription but it's at the high end of the budget. It makes sense if Expression comes with it though.

It's for a one man development show, making an LOB app that will integrate video/audo and mic/webcam equipment.

Comment: Maybe you are eligible for the Microsoft BizSpark program?

Comment: @Pierre 303: I've taken a look at it, and the boss is applying, but from what I can tell of the requirements, we don't qualify (been in business for a number of years now).

Comment: May be this pdf will help. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2010/10/26/silverlight-developer-guidance-map.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can actually develop Silverlight applications with the Web Express edition of Visual Studio so the Pro version would work to.

I'd also recommend getting Expression Blend - if only to get access to the options for copying and modifying style templates.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for Microsoft Expression Blend. I remember that earlier version had a buggy source code editor, but I hope this one is fixed.

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford it I would definitely recommend VS2010 Premium w/ MSDN, which therefore gives you access to Blend.  Using Silverlight from a developer perspective, I find that some things are easier to accomplish in VS2010, and some things are easier in Blend.  In fact some things are just impossible through the VS2010 designer that are trivial in Blend.  Knowing and using both definitely gives you an advantage.